# Ripple Simulator html page change not working with Visual studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, ripple

I have made cordova project using Visual studio 2015.

I am building this application with cordova version 5.4.0

In application i am using two html pages respectively page1.html , page2.html

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {               
                window.location.href = 'page2.html';
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here.Page 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When page redirection called ripple simulator gives error like this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmb3u.png)

Not getting any idea , What is the problem.
As far as have observed ripple simulator causing this when it encounters page redirection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**The temporary fix is to install an older version of chrome:** http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome-46-0-2490-80-enterprise-version

This is a bug in chrome described here, no fix out to date (2016/02/09): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585260

My emulated ripple app was working 100%, but starting getting the same "aw snap" message appearing starting Feb 2016, without me changing any code. 
I just installed chrome 46 and its now working just fine.

*You will have to disable automatic updates for chrome, which I guess is not ideal security wise, but until someone fixes something somewhere, it does the trick for me.*

Comment: perhaps duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210947/proplem-with-visual-studio-2015-and-ripple

Answer (score 0):

<s>Seeing this is a [bug in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585260), perhaps could try to set Visual Studio to run emulation in a different browser? (Firefox or Edge)</s>

Nevermind, looks like [only chrome is supported](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585260)

Comment: nevermind, looks like only chrome is supported: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/