# Proplem with Visual studio 2015 and Ripple

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, ripple

When I run the application with Visual Studio and ripple, and I click link for other pages from Cordova project( to localhost) comes an error. Ripple notificates: "Instead of the page you'll see an AW, snap!"  Chromes DeveloperTools tells: "was disconnected from the page.'
Links for some website works good. Before links worked well.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

We found what appears to be a bug in Chromium and filed this to track it:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585260

We are making a change to Ripple to work around the issue. Please keep an eye on our VS TACO blog for more information; we'll make an announcement when the change goes live with instructions on how to update Ripple. You can find our blog here:

http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/

We're sorry for any inconvenience this has caused you and hope to have a fix, both in our tools and in Chrome, shortly.

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

I followed instructions from http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/12/update-to-ripple.html

and it's working :

-In Visual Studio, click Tools -> Options

-Find the Tools for Apache Cordova

-Click the “Clear Cordova Cache” button

-Rebuild your project

Comment: Now Ripple works well. Thanks a lot for fixing and solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have VS2015 TACO tools update 5. let me know if you have any issues afterwards. It works great for me with the latest update.

Comment: I found the error, it was in Chrome. I installed old Chrome(46.0.2490.80) and Ripple works now. It took two weeks to find error reason. Thanks for this site.

Comment: I have too both updated and it not works.  I noticed that I am not the only one that gets this error. This is very annoying error.

Answer (score 0):

Luck did not last a long time. Chrome updated himself(Versio 48.0.2564.103 m) and Ripple does not again working. In new Chromes is bug with Visual Studio 2015 and Ripple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new issue we're investigating on the VS TACO team, too. I'll update this answer with any workarounds/next steps as we keep researching.

For now, the workaround is as suggested by @PeteQoo - you need to revert your version of Chrome to version 46.